# Get the Time of Last update of a column

Tags: mysql, information-schema, row-modification-time

This command gives the date of the last update for a table

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MyDB'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'
```

But I want to find the time of last update of a particular column of a table. 
I can't use triggers because I want to know the time of last update of a specific column from a system table.

I hope I explained well my problem.

Answer (score 6):

None of the system tables (that is, [nothing in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html)) exist that has that kind of information recorded anywhere. In other words, there is no native mechanism to put any timestamps on column changes. Any time that

- one or more columns change in any row
- a new row is added
- an old is deleted
- an ALTER TABLE of any kind

the [`UPDATE_TIME` column in **`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html) is updated.

## SUGGESTION

This may be a bitter pill to swallow, but you must do the following:

- Create a custom table that records

  - primary key
  - column name
  - the old value of that column
  - the new value of that column
  - timestamp of the change
- Create `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger to compare old and new columns and record it if they do not match

## EPILOGUE

This may not be so bad if you are customizing for a few tables and a few columns.

Comment: The `UPDATE_TIME` column in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` is only updated for `MyISAM` tables, not for `InnoDB`. Refrain from depending on this value.

Comment: @ShlomiNoach what was I thinking? I just answered this one on that : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17341149/491757

Comment: So bad, for ur suggestion I can't use triggers because I want to know the time of last update of a specific column from a system table. And Thanks for ur answer.

Comment: @dardar.moh I don't think you can do that unless you'd have permissions to information_schema's tables and the trigger would do the alteration there, which I'm assuming you don't. IMO mysql/mariadb are simply missing update_time in the `columns` table` ...

Answer (score 4):

What you could is change your table so it stores the timestamp whenever it is updated.
For example

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY
  x INT,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
                     ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  KEY (updated_at)
);
```

The above code store the current timestamp to a new row and changes it the time edited whenever a row is edited. This way you can get the data, sort it (`order by`) in `descending` mode and get the top record. That way you get the last updated record in your table. 
If you want to know for the whole database then you have to compare the last updated record for each of your tables and get the most recent one.